# How do open child sockets get closed?

Tags: c, sockets

I have spawned a child process on a while(1) loop that appears to accept ongoing TCP connections. I am looking for confirmation of 'normal' behaviour of a socket child process, assuming the parent process is not dead (I found plenty of advice on how to kill child processes when the parent is dead...).

```
void 
dostuff (int sock, int* count)
{
  while(1){
    *count = *count +1;

    char cnt[20];
    sprintf(cnt, "count: %d\n", *count);

    int n;
    char buffer[bufsize];       
    bzero(buffer,bufsize);

    n = read(sock,buffer,bufsize);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    fprintf(stderr,"From the client:\n%s",buffer);

    char reply[bufsize];
    bzero(reply, bufsize);
    strcat(reply, cnt);

    n = write(sock, reply, bufsize);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
  }
}
```

I suspect the child process will automatically close when its TCP session is finished, is this correct?

It appears when reconnecting to its current TCP session, the child in effect start at the top of the while loop, incrementing count before reading and writing. Can I rely on this behaviour? Or make it reliable?

Comment: `fprintf(stderr,"From the client:\n%s",buffer);` is not good: `read` don't add trailing '\0' so `buffer` is not a printable string (in that way).

Comment: but why the child would go out of this loop? You never exit/return/break in it (or maybe in `error()` function, but its content is not shown.

Comment: buffer in this case populated with '\0' before writing to it.

Comment: And what if you get exactly (or more) `buffsize` data (note: "more" means that you will get exactly buffsize data, of course)? Whatever for your main question nothing in this code let suppose that the loop will ends.

Comment: If `n` is zero you should close the socket and exit the loop. If `n` is negative you should log the error, close the socket, and exit the loop. In neither case should you continue as though you had received data. And if `n` is positive you should treat it as the number of bytes that were actually read. Not make assumptions about trailing nulls.

Comment: @EJP Are you saying that the socket/TCP session being closed, would be picked up by the read? Is the loop blocked by the read until a new packet arrives (which might explain why the write isn't continuously writing)?

Comment: If socket is present without content the loop is blocked in the `read`. If it is closed the `read` will failed (-1) but write will failed too (it is the same socket!)

Comment: Thats what I needed to know, thank you. If you knock that up as an answer, I will tick it. Cheers.

Comment: @Matt That's exactly what I said. If the connection is closed, new data cannot ever possibly arrive, so what exactly would be the point of blocking?

Answer (score 0):

So first coding problems: the `fprintf(stderr,"From the client:\n%s",buffer);`. Even if `buffer` is inited with zeros you may get `bufsize` bytes, so the `fprintf` will read data after end of buffer. And you are in a loop so each read could gives a different size, so you may whatever print "garbage" from previous buffer content.
You should use functions that takes a number of chars to write (i.e. `fwrite`).

An other point is more a "style" problem: you get `n` bytes from your read, so why writing back `bufsize` bytes and not `n`? The only advantage is to have "constant size" messages.

For the inner loop none of the functions in it are able to leave this loop, or the function, or the program.
You must explicitly leave the loop (using `break`) or the function (using `return`) or even the program (with `exit`), depending on your needs.

In its current state the function reads from the socket. It then prints an error message but continues its job (it is up to you to decide what to do in case of read error). After it prints the message (probably the previous one as you don't clean content) and writes to the socket, which will fail (if the socket is closed, you can't read, you can't write).

So here the main point for you: trying to read/write from/to a closed socket just returns -1 from `read/write` functions. It's up to you to decide what to do after that.

The function should looks like:

```
void dostuff (int sock, int* count) {
  while(1){
    int n;
    *count = *count + 1;
    char buffer[bufsize];
    n = read(sock,buffer,bufsize);
    if (n <= 0) {
      error("ERROR reading from socket (or EOF)");
      close(sock); // close our side whatever
      break;  // leave the loop (or return)
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"From the client:\n");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, n, stderr); // write the n elements
    char reply[bufsize];
    reply[0] = '\0';  // no need to clear all buffer
    strcat(reply, cnt);
    n = write(sock, reply, n);  // just write N elements
    if (n < 0) {
      error("ERROR writing to socket");
      close(sock); // close our side whatever
      break; // not able to write -> problem
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `error()`, whatever it is, going to know whether to print `errno` etc if you don't pass `n` to it? And why would you call a function called `error()` at end of stream, which isn't an error? You shouldn't handle `n == -1` and `n == 0` In the same block. You need two tests.

Comment: @EJP: this is the function of the OP. I did not changed it. Whatever any function can access `errno` until you don't perform an other syscall before. Yes, -1 and 0 should be separated.

Comment: @hexasoft I am happy to acknowledge the actual help which is related to confirming that the read function blocks until a socket has a message to read and that it will fail if the TCP connection closes. The rest is teaching me to suck eggs and making sweeping assumptions about the code involved. For example, what do you think the error() function does... Google DRY. Regardless, it wasn't relevant to the question. I am still happy to acknowledge the actual help, assuming you choose to confine your answer to the question asked.